# Multiple regression: Is there evidence for regional variation in wages?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

I'm stuck with this problem and was wondering if anyone could help explain why it is what it is. Currently I'm doing old exams and there is this question I just can't understand.

The model is the one below and the true/false question I'm having trouble with is.

"There is evidence for regional variation in wages"

How am I suppose to go about regaring a question like this. My thought was that R^2 is not 0 so therefore there must be variation in the model. But it can't be that easy. Explanations would be appreciated.

[image: Multiple regression]

Answer (score 2):

The $R^2$ checks the whole model. You have experience as well as region, so a large $R^2$ doesn't mean region is important--it might just be experience.

The $F$ statistic at the bottom is an explicit test for whether geography matters if you hold experience constant (i.e. if we compare two equally experienced people, one in each region, would I expect that their wages are different?). The $p$-value for the $F$ statistic is <0.025 (your $\alpha$), therefore there is evidence that wages are different.